# Does SQL Server Date Correlation Optimization only work on DateTime fields, or will a Date work, too?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I ask because this is an older feature that I just discovered recently. The documentation mentions DateTime a few times but doesn't explicitly say that other date types are compatible or not.

I have a Data Warehouse that I believe could benefit from this, but 90% of the dates that matter are Date types, not DateTime. I am on SQL 2014, but information on any version would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works for both `date` and `datetime` columns. The experiment is rather simple - create a database with the option on, create tables with both types, insert data that satisfies a correlation pattern (like all dates in one table are after the dates in the other table), run some queries that exploit that pattern, and then observe the auto-created stats are the same for both sets of tables.

Create the database and turn on the option:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE splut;
GO
ALTER DATABASE splut SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION ON;
GO
USE splut;
GO
```

Create two tables with correlated `date` columns, and two tables with correlated `datetime` columns:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.d1(id int primary key, d date);
CREATE TABLE dbo.d2(id int not null foreign key references dbo.d1(id), d date);
CREATE TABLE dbo.d3(id int primary key, d datetime);
CREATE TABLE dbo.d4(id int not null foreign key references dbo.d3(id), d datetime);
GO
```

Insert some correlated data:

```
INSERT dbo.d1(id, d) SELECT DISTINCT ABS(object_id),'20190101' FROM sys.all_objects;
INSERT dbo.d2(id, d) SELECT id,DATEADD(DAY, ABS(id)%20, '20190101') FROM dbo.d1;
INSERT dbo.d3(id, d) SELECT DISTINCT ABS(object_id),'20190101' FROM sys.all_objects;
INSERT dbo.d4(id, d) SELECT id,DATEADD(DAY, ABS(id)%20, '20190101') FROM dbo.d3;
```

Now run a query that *might* benefit from correlation statistics (though, really, any join will do):

```
SELECT TOP (10) * FROM dbo.d1 INNER JOIN dbo.d2 ON d1.d = d2.d;
SELECT TOP (10) * FROM dbo.d3 INNER JOIN dbo.d4 ON d3.d = d4.d;
```

Now, check the stats:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id), s.name, s.stats_id, 
   sc.stats_column_id, c.name, c.system_type_id, t.name
FROM sys.stats AS s 
INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc
ON s.object_id = sc.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
ON sc.object_id = c.object_id AND sc.column_id = c.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.types AS t
ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id, s.stats_id) AS p
WHERE s.auto_created = 1 AND OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id) IN (N'd1',N'd2',N'd3',N'd4');
```

Results on my machine (your stats names will vary) show that stats are created both on `(id, date/datetime column of parent)` and `(date/datetime column of child)`:

> [image]

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader if this holds true for `time`, `datetime2`, and `datetimeoffset`, or if it will also work if one column is `date` and the other is `datetime`.